# Using framework builded in new Xcode in my old project in old Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

I have my project in Xcode 10.1 with Swift 3 and I am using 20+ frameworks and everything was fine till few days ago when some of frameworks decided that they need to release fix for critical bug for iOS 13. So when I update my pods and run my project it said

```
could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1001.0.46.4.0_0' Reader: '1000.11.45.5_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 10.0.0, (clang-1000.11.45.5)' for architecture arm64
```

OK so that means that they build their project in newer Xcode then I am working on (I guess they are using the last one 10.3) and then I try to set bitcode to false on my main target but guess what error is the same..

Ok so I download their demo project and this fix about bitcode worked so I am not sure what is wrong with my project why this bitcode = NO does not work. I only disabled bitcode on my main target do I need to set that on some other place or something?

Not sure is this relevant but I have 2 Xcodes parallel 10.1 and 10.3

I have this problem a few days.

This app that I am using is Appboy-iOS-SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've had similar issues to you with the Braze (Appboy) SDK.

After investigating, we've found that this issue only affects apps built with Xcode 11 or greater, so there's no need to update the SDK unless you're planning to build and submit your app using Xcode 11, which is not required even after iOS 13 is released. We're leaving the SDK at the old version and have found no issue here.

If you would like to update regardless, still using Xcode 10.x you'll need to get around the mismatch by turning off bitcode. To have success with this, you'll need to disable it on both the config for your project/workspace, and for Appboy-iOS-SDK. If you're using Cocoapods to manage dependencies, you would be best off adding this to your Podfile so it doesn't get reset to `YES` each time you run `pod install`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if target.name == 'Appboy-iOS-SDK'
        config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

All that said, I think the answer is just to do this upgrade *only* when you upgrade your build machine to use Xcode 11.